# Error on installing new modules in dnn7

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

[image]

> "ExceptionSystem.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyProject\DesktopModules\PaymentInfo\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider' is denied"

whenever I'm trying to install a new custom modules in dnn7, I got the above errors. (also refer the attached image.)

I also checked the Files/Folders permission in IIS, its fine.

For my clarification, I upload all the module packages from the path:

> C:\Documents\src\DotNetNuke\DesktopModules\ReviewModule\install\ReviewModule_00.00.01_Source(Install).zip

This is the path which I have configured in IIS for my DNN site, but it creates folder in some other path:

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot(MyProject)\DesktopModules\PaymentInfo\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider.

Is this default procedure for DNN?

But if I upload those same packages in another dnn site in another environment, I works fine and no issues in module installation.

Comment: I think you need to change the folder permissions in Windows itself. Even if it may seem to be correct in IIS. You can test this by giving read/write permissions to `Everyone` for the `DesktopModules` folder. Note: do not do this for live websites on a public server.

Comment: @VDWWD ..Thank you for your response. I also tried those steps by giving  read/write permissions to Everyone for the DesktopModules folder but still am getting a same error.